# JFreeChart TimeSeries updating Seconds

Tags: java, time-series, jfreechart

I'm trying to create a TimeSeries chart to display my data in seconds. I have the length of time that I need saved here,

```
ParseReader.length.get(0)
```

This contains for this example 00:47:47.

When I try to add data to the chart using,

```
    for(int i=0; i<60; i++) {
        String splitt[] = ParseReader.length.get(0).split(":");
        s1.addOrUpdate(new Second(new Date(Integer.valueOf(splitt[2]), Integer.valueOf(splitt[1]), Integer.valueOf(splitt[0]), 1, 1, 2013)), ParseReader.hrBody.get(i));
    }
```

Now I know this will just add everything on the same spot I just don't know how to change it so that it will plot each point in hrBody until it reaches the time limit as it plots everything on the 00:47:47 marker. Also, if I change the i<60 to anything above that it just returns a null error.

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, problem is, that everything is plotted at the same time spot.
This could be because you are calling the .get method always using the same index - 0. Maybe you should use:

```
String splitt[] = ParseReader.length.get(i).split(":");
```

Also, your creation of Date seems redundant. Second in jFreeChart has also [this](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Second.html#Second%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) constructor, that accepts int values for second, minute, hour, day, month and year.

As to the null pointer error - I can't give a solution for this, because you didn't show us the code for get method. But please note, TimeSeriesChart supports null values - it will plot a gap in the chart.